# Is it possible to eta (or otherwise) reduce arguments if I depend on them?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I was solving a super simple problem and came out with this code. I *feel* like there should be a way to eliminate arguments `x` and `y` in `areaOrPerimeter`. But I can't find a way to do it. Is it possible to get rid of them somehow? I have a strong feeling that it should be possible.

```
areaOrPerimeter :: Double -> Double -> Double
areaOrPerimeter x y
  | x == y = area x y 
  | otherwise = perimeter x y
  

area :: Num a => a -> a -> a
area = (*)

perimeter :: Num a => a -> a -> a
perimeter x y = 2 * (x + y)
```

Comment: pointfree.io suggests `ap (ap . ap (ap . (if' .) . (==)) area) perimeter` -- but why should one use that?

Comment: If you change it to `areaOrPerimeter x y = (areaOrPerimeterFunction x y) x y` then `areaOrPerimeterFunction` could return either `area` or `perimeter` without having to apply them immediately. The problem is you are using the arguments twice. Is there a reason why you don't want to write the arguments?

Comment: You almost certainly _don't_ want to return either an area or a perimeter. Those have different physical dimension. Perhaps area or perimeter-squared could make sense.

Comment: Also, always think twice before making any equality check on floating-point numbers. It's very easy to end up with two floats that seem they _should_ be equal, but are actually a tiny bit apart. It usually makes more sense to check only `<` or `>` relations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to have a chance of doing that in a non-obnoxious way, you should first group together the arguments meaningfully to avoid having to deal with multiple parameters:

```
data RectangleSize a = RectangleSize {width, height :: a}
```

Then we can make the functions and the `x==y` check more meaningful too:

```
area :: Num a => RectangleSize a -> a
area (RectangleSize w h) = w*h

perimeter :: Num a => RectangleSize a -> a
perimeter (RectangleSize w h) = 2*(w+h)

isSquare :: Eq a => RectangleSize a -> Bool
isSquare (RectangleSize w h) = w==h
```

That leaves us with the already more promising

```
areaOrPerimeter :: RectangleSize Double -> Double
areaOrPerimeter r
  | isSquare r  = area r 
  | otherwise   = perimeter r
```

To make that point-free, you still need to copy around the `r` three times. This can be done (whether it *should* is another matter) with the `Applicative` instance of functions, namely `\x -> f x (g x)` can be written as `f<*>g`. In this case, you want to make a decision, so you require a first-class `if`; typically that's written

```
if' :: Bool -> a -> a -> a
if' True x _ = x
if' False _ y = y
```

Now you can upgrade `isSquare` to a switching function by composing with `if'`:

```
    if' . isSquare :: Eq a => RectangleSize a -> b -> b -> b
```

And now we can use the applicative instance to distribute the rectangle to all components:

```
areaOrPerimeter = if'.isSquare <*> area <*> perimeter
```

Actually not too shabby IMO.

Answer (score 1):

To chain two single parameter functions `f` and `g`, `.` is pretty forward. To chain `g :: c -> d` and `f :: a -> b -> c`, use `(g .) . f`. That way, you can write `perimeter` as

`perimeter = ((2*) .) . (+)`

one parameter can be removed with `<*>`, do that twice for two parameters:

```
import Control.Applicative(liftA2)
import Data.Bool(bool)

areaOrPerimeter :: Double -> Double -> Double
areaOrPerimeter = bool <<$>> (*) <<*>> ((2*) .) . (+) <<*>> (==)
   where infixl 4 <<*>>
         (<<*>>) = liftA2 (<*>)
         infixl 5 <<$>>
         (<<$>>) = fmap . fmap
```

Writing point-free is a nice exercise, but don't expect to understand this in 6 months from now.